# Puntero usado en la inicialización de una variable

Tags: c, punteros

Tengo algunos problemas a la hora de iniciar una variable local dentro de una función.

Por ejemplo:

```
int function(int *pointer1)
{
    int a = *pointer1;


    int b = 0;
    int *p = &b;
}
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre la asignación del entero `a` y del `*p`?

Para mí creo que lo mismo, pero quizás haya alguna diferencia que esté pasando por alto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explico cada uno por separado:

```
int a = *pointer1;
```

En esta línea se está asignando a la variable entera `a` el valor entero al que apunta el puntero `pointer1`.

```
int b = 0;
int *p = &b;
```

Se está creando un puntero a entero (`int *`) llamado `p` que apunta a la dirección de memoria donde se almacena el valor entero `b`.

En el primer caso el asterisco es un operador de "acceso al contenido de memoria" (`*pointer1`) y en el segundo caso es un modificador del tipo de dato que indica que será un "puntero a ese tipo de dato" (`int *`).

Nota adicional: Mientras que el contenido de `*pointer1` persistirá tras salir de la ejecución de esa función, el contenido de `*p` desaparece (sigue existiendo, pero podrá ser sobreescrito por la llamada a otras funciones). Por lo que esto podría darte problemas:

```
int *function(int *pointer1)
{
    int a = *pointer1;


    int b = 0;
    int *p = &b;
    return p;
}

int main() {
    int a = 0, *b;
    b = function(&a);
    /* El contenido de "b" está comprometido (leer aclaración) */
    printf("%d\n", *b);
    return 0;
}
```

En la llamada a `printf` el valor de `b`  está comprometido porque apunta a un valor de memoria de la pila que ha sido liberada tras la llamada a `function`, de modo que la llamada a otra función podría reutilizar esa zona de memoria y alterar su contenido.

Herramientas como `valgrind` te informarán de este tipo de problemas de memoria:

```
==13964== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==13964==    at 0x4E8099B: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==13964==    by 0x4E84636: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1660)
==13964==    by 0x4E8B3D8: printf (printf.c:33)
==13964==    by 0x400588: main (in /tmp/prueba)
==13964==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==13964==    at 0x40056E: main (in /tmp/prueba)
```

El texto "Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation" indica que se está haciendo uso de un valor sin inicializar alojado en memoria en la pila por la llamada a una función.